# React Having Two classes with Two sets of state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React. I have a small app I'm designing with a schedule and with list of products.  Please see my component diagram, below.

I propose that The Schedule Controller and Product Control each will be a class with state.

I brought all the Product modules (a listing component and its children, A new product form, a product detail module, and an edit product module) to be direct children of the Product Controller to prevent excess prop drilling, so they can all pull from the product control class state.

So, as I'm thinking about this, I'm mindful of a single source of truth and to concentrate a single state.  However, I've always done that because the whole app has one class.

It seems to me that, to obey those laws (and without using a store as in Redux, which I'm not ready to work my way up to yet.  This is a learning exercise and I want to get some proficiency with regular React before adding a whole new library to my learning) I should pick the highest parent component and make only one class with one state.

It seems to me that when I use setState(), its going to the use the state of the class it inherits from.  Right?  And that state isn't going to get confused about which state to use, because its going to the parent class (I'm totally out on a limb here).  The product modules will be extended from the Product class and setState() will only go up the chain to the parent and the parent state.

Or is the correct approach to squash the schedule modules as children of the product controller?

I did a lot of looking around and the references I keep finding are much more complex than what I'm attempting here (involving two different classes with state that DO share information, that's not happening here).  I may not be searching the correct terms.  So I'm sorry if this is something well known.

So the question I have is, is this a bad idea or bad practice?

[image: component diagram]

Comment: `setState` is a stable function that corresponds to the component that created it. It will always change state only to that component.

Comment: also you're a bit inconsistent with your naming. Sometimes you call the component Product Control and sometimes Product Controller and on your scheme it's Products Control

Comment: a single source of truth principle doesn't mean that there must be just one class with a single state. The idea is that you mustn't keep the same state in two places (because they might go out of sync and that's really bad). It's actually quite hard to do in React  (which is one of its biggest strengths - it imposes good practices on you aka it pushes you towards the pit of success). It's absolutely okay to have many stateful components.

Comment: Thank you!  Sorry about the naming inconsistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A setState call in a class Component only sets the state of itself.
There are two forms of class state

**State**-> This will be the local state of the class. It will be changed and maintained by the class which declares it.

**Props**-> These are states/properties which are passed from the parent to the child class. This value cannot the changed. Only the parent class which owns these props has the power to change it. The only way to change this would be through lifting the state. You are right here.
Refer https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Thank you Sultan!

Answer (score 0):

marzelin had the answer in the comments above.  Thanks!